# Does it matter if a function within a React component is not pure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, coding-style

If I create a helper function to tidy up the internal logic of a react component, is it ok if it references one of the props directly? Or is that a code smell and should I be passing in that prop as an extra argument in order to have a pure function?

Contrived example of component with non-pure helper function:

```
function SomeBankComponent({ accountData }) {
  const getMessage = () => {
    if (accountData.frozen) {
      return "your account is frozen";
    } else {
      return `you have ${accountData.savings} left in your account`;
    }
  };

  // ... rest of the component ...
```

In the above is it wise to change it to `const getMessage = (accountData) => {`? Or is it simply a matter of personal/team/project style preference?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Answer (score 1):

No problem, actually it's normal to reference directly state and some given props at your component's helper functions.

below, it is a little refactor, which is more of a matter of preference :)

```
  const getMessage = () => (
    accountData.frozen
      ? 'your account is frozen'
      : `you have ${accountData.savings} left in your account`
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

In the previous version of this answer I wrote wrongly:

> This is not an impure function.

But I was wrong. The mutability of props leads to the break of referencial transparency. 
In the comments @JaredSmith highlighed my mistake.

I leave the remaining part of the answer, just in case it could help somebody (but don't make the same mistake of mine :) )

---

Let's start from the concept of purity.
A function is called pure when, for any given input, it returns a value.

Some examples of pure functions:

```
const double: (x: number) => number = x => x * 2

const foo: () => string = () => 'foo'
```

Note that in languages like Scala `()` is actually a type with a single value: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Unit.html

Some examples of **not pure** functions:

```
const divide2By: (x: number) => number = x => 2 / x
```

The latter breaks the definition of pure function. 
When `x = 0` it simply can't compute any divition and an error is thrown.

Purity is a concept thightly bounded to the concepts of [**referencial transparency**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) and it's required for [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)).

Referential transparency is very important: a function is referential transparent when for the same input it returns **always** the same output.
We could say that the function is totally deterministic with respect to the input arguments.

You might ask: yes, but my function depends on the context (the react component) so it's not referential transparent.

Actually it still is R.T.
We should always consider the entire closure of the function (code + context data).
If the context changes then the function itself changes.

The important thing is that the function is R.T within the same context.

I hope it was helpful. Good luck :)

Comment: The `getMessage` function depends on the value a closed-over mutable variable (props.account). It is not pure.

Comment: @JaredSmith Any prop change is propagated and leads to the creation of another closure. The result of `getMessage` is always sync with those props change so it is referencial transparent with respect to the entire component.

All the higher order function stuff is based on inherit values from the context, is it everything not pure because of this?

Comment: It is not pure. It is still possible (however inadvisable) to mutate the props object directly without using setState or its hook equivalent. It won't trigger a rerender obviously, but it will cause that function to return a different value. Unless you can call the function with the same inputs and always get the same result no matter what, it is not pure.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you, you're right, I was taking for granted readonlyness of props :(